SQL Server query with common table expression suspended with pageiolatch_sh
I have a cte based query which runs for a very long time, and on the Activity Monitor for the query there are multiple rows showing the query is suspended in pageiolatch_sh. The strange thing is that this occurs only when executed using CTE (as first code bellow). If I use a temporary table instead (as in the second code bellow) it finish in a split-second.
Any idea what can cause this?
QUERY1:
with cte AS(
select a.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate) as row_number
    from tbl_ShiurimList a
        inner join tbl_FolderStructure b on a.MainFolderID=b.FolderID
    where contains(NodeKeyPath,'0057900 and not (00058058 or 00057901 or 000401980)')
        and isnull(IsDeleted,0)=0
)
select * from cte where row_number=5

QUERY2:
select a.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate) as row_number
into #temp
from tbl_ShiurimList a
    inner join tbl_FolderStructure b on a.MainFolderID=b.FolderID
where contains(NodeKeyPath,'0057900 and not (00058058 or 00057901 or 000401980)')
    and isnull(IsDeleted,0)=0

select * from #temp where row_number=5


How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions

The cardinality estimate using a CTE or table variable is notorious for causing performance issues.  There are no records when the batch is compiled so the plan will be optimized for few records.  A nested loop lookup can be the result even if there are millions of records.  I guess this is the case here.  You can look at the execution plans to see what they are really doing.  If you have an older version of SQL, you will be missing optimization (e.g., recompile) made over the years to get a better estimate.
FYI "(IsDeleted = 0 OR IsDeleted IS NULL)" allows an index to be used.  This does not mean it will be used (e.g., not selective).  A function like ISNULL "covers" the column so that an index can't be used.
FYI When using an alias, please specify the alias on each column.  I can't tell what table the column is from.
